# My website xml feed is only showing single page

Tags: wordpress, web

I've a Wordpress website and this is my [blog page](https://www.technicalya.com/blog). I changed that on one page we can only show 10 posts after that we need to go to another page i.e. page 2. The problem is when I'm trying to check the feed it is only showing single page feed and page 2,3,... is not showing in the rss.

[The way we navigate to another page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W8RMR.png)

Answer (score 0):

We can do that from Settings >> Readings >> Syndication feeds show the most recent. Change the number from default 10 to whatever you want.